# Polynomial rings quotient and remainder

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Find the quotient and remainder when $x^3+2$ is divided by $2x^2+3x+2$ in $\mathbb Z[x], \mathbb Z_3[x],$ and $\mathbb Z_5[x]$.

So I figured I would start just solving in the general $\mathbb Z[x]$. I'm just not sure how to get $2x^2$ to cancel $x^3$? Could someone help me get things started?

Comment: @walkar This is what I want to do but I don't know my first move. If I simply multiply $2x^2$ by $x$ then I'm still left with $-x^3$

Comment: You can only divide by a polynomial when its leading coefficient is a unit, and $2$ is not a unit in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @Quasicoherent is $\mathbb Z[x]$ not just the general $\mathbb Z_n$, i.e. all integers?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  $\mathbb{Z}$ is the set of all integers.  $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is (I assume) the integers modulo $n$, also denoted $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.  $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is the set of polynomials with integer coefficients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot divide $x^3+2$ by $2x^2+3x+2$ over $\mathbb Z$ because $2$ is not invertible. Indeed, $(2x^2+3x+2)(ax+b)$ has an even leading coefficient $2a$ and so can never be $1$.

However, you can divide $4(x^3+2)$ by $2x^2+3x+2$:
$$
4(x^3+2) = (2x^2+3x+2)(2x-3)+(5x+14)
$$
This also helps when doing it mod $3$ and mod $5$.